# T-SQL: How to join tables without creating extra rows - need a one row to one row correspondance

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, iteration, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a scenario where I need to join two SQL tables and am struggling with how to do it.
Let's say in table A I have this:

```
ColA  ColB   ColC   ColD
45     55     17     45
45     55     17     47
45     55     17     49
45     55     17     51
```

And in Table B I have this:

```
ColA  ColB   ColC   ColE
45     55     17     55
45     55     17     56
45     55     17     57
45     55     17     58
```

I need to create a table that looks like this - note only the  4 rows, not the 16 that the inner join I was using produces.

```
ColA  ColB   ColC   ColD   ColE
45     55     17     45     55
45     55     17     47     56
45     55     17     49     57
45     55     17     51     58
```

I'm pretty much out of ideas.  Both tables will always have the same number of rows.  Is there a way to do this using joins, or should I iterate through the table A (ie get the row number) and get the matching row number in Table B?

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which version of SQl Server are you using, and how do you determine the order in which they match. Also, Have a look at ROW_NUMBER http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming at least SQL Server 2005

```
WITH T1
     AS (SELECT *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ColA, ColB, ColC ORDER BY ColD)
                RN
         FROM   TableA),
     T2
     AS (SELECT *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ColA, ColB, ColC ORDER BY ColE)
                RN
         FROM   TableB)
SELECT T1.ColA,
       T1.ColB,
       T1.ColC,
       T1.ColD,
       T2.ColE
FROM   T1
       JOIN T2
         ON T1.ColA = T2.ColA
            AND T1.ColB = T2.ColB
            AND T1.ColC = T2.ColC
            AND T1.RN = T2.RN
```

Comment: Yup, this is what I would have recomended too.

Comment: This solution gave me exactly what I was looking for!!  Thanks so much, you guys are amazing!